# SQL Server create assembly which references another assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have .NET class library which uses Quartz.dll

When i register assembly in sql its says that Quartz.dll requeres system.web, system.drawing, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols...

It is not possible to create assembly without this dlls?

I have installed on my server .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0

Quartz.dll version is 1.0.3.3

Comment: Are you trying to use Quartz.Net to schedule jobs inside SQL Server process hosted assemblies? Don't.

Answer (score 0):

place these dlls with quartz.dll.